Prevent Gitlab CI from double wrapping release artifacts?
Currently I produce an artifact package.zip. I want this to be the directly downloadable artifact asset. However, the Gitlab release artifact asset link always wraps this in an additional zip.
I.e. archive.zip which contains package.zip. Changing artifact name only changes the top zip. I just want Gitlab to directly provide a download to package.zip without the top level.
I can't have the artifact be the contents of package.zip as this is built separately. I need to package.zip as is.
Edit:
Specifically "Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator..."  - how can this be changed?
